# How can I extract the Exception from a faulted Result?

Tags: c#, language-ext

Please see code below, I am using the `LanguageExt.Common.Result` class:

```
public async Task<Result<bool>> DoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        await Something();
        return new Result<bool>(true);
    }
    catch (MyException ex)
    {
        return new Result<bool>(ex);
    }
}
```

And this

```
public async Task<Result<MyClass>> DoNext()
{
    var result = await DoSomething();

    if (result.IsFaulted)
    {
        return new Result<MyClass>(GET_EXCEPTION_FROM_result); // <<==== HERE ===
    }

    var data = new MyClass();
    return new Result<MyClass>(data);
}
```

How can I extract the exception from the faulted result ?

I know I can use `result.Match<Result<MyClass>>(SuccessLambda, failureLambda)` but the lambdas can not be async.

################# ADDED ###############

The first version of DoNext looked like this:

```
public async Task<Result<MyClass>> DoNext()
{
    var result = await DoSomething();

    return result.Match<Result<MyClass>>(
        async canDo => {
            var myClass = await GetAsync(...);
            return new Result<Myclass>(myclass);
        },
        ex => new Result<MyClass>(ex);
    )
}
```

But the lambdas can not be async.

Comment: So the real question is how to process Result asynchronously, not extract the parts? What are you trying to do asynchronously?

Comment: Have you tried `MatchAsync` ?

Comment: Not yet tried MatchAsync, let me try that.

Comment: There is no MatchAsync. I found MapAsync instead, and I used it, see the answer below.

Comment: [MatchAsync returns hits in 56 files](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Alouthy%2Flanguage-ext%20matchasync&type=code) in the Github repo

Comment: Seems to be on the MTask<A> class, not the Result<A> class. Result only have: Map, MapAsync, and Match as methods starting with Ma*

Comment: That's probably intentional - the only reason to want an async `Success` func is because you intend to map it to another result, not just handle it. So only `MapAsync` got an async version, by design

Comment: According to https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/Common/Result/ you should avoid using `Result<T>` in your code. Have a look at `TryAsync<T>`/`Try<T>` or maybe `Aff<T>`/`Eff<T>` or `Fin<T>` or `Either<Exception,T>` (combined with Task<>).

Comment: I am not really practicing FP in my App, I just wanted a Result Object, that will be fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally got the right way to do that, you should stay functional:

```
public async Task<Result<MyClass>> DoNext()
{
    var result = await DoSomething();

    return await result.MapAsync<MyClass>(async canDo =>
    {
        var myClass = await GetAsync(...);
        return myclass;
    });
}
```

You map the success path to another object. Any error state coming from the first Result object will be transferred to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

@AztecCodes, it seems like the API has changed. There is no overload of `IfFail` returning an exception, so I instead did this (Please let me know if I missed something):

```
if (result.IsSuccess)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    Exception exception = default!;
    result.IfFail(ex => exception = ex);
    return new Result<MyClass>(exception);
}
```